# How to execute a (safe) bash shell command within setup.py?

Tags: python, setuptools, nunjucks

I use nunjucks for templating the frontend in a python project.  Nunjucks templates *must* be precompiled in production.  I don't use extensions or asynchronous filters in the nunjucks templates.  Rather than use grunt-task to listen for changes to my templates, I prefer to use the nunjucks-precompile command (offered via npm) to sweep the entire templates directory into templates.js.

The idea is to have the `nunjucks-precompile --include ["\\.tmpl$"] path/to/templates > templates.js` command execute within setup.py so I can simply piggyback our deployer scripts' regular execution.

I found [a setuptools override](http://www.niteoweb.com/blog/setuptools-run-custom-code-during-install) and [a distutils scripts argument](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.run_setup) might serve the right purpose, but I'm not so sure either is the simplest approach to execution.

Another approach is to use `subprocess` to execute the command directly within setup.py, but I've been cautioned against this (rather preemptively IMHO). I don't really deeply understand why not.

Any ideas? Affirmations? Confirmations?

**Update (04/2015):** - If you don't have the `nunjucks-precompile` command available, simply use Node Package Manager to install nunjucks like so:

```
$ npm install nunjucks
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pardon the quick self-answer.  I hope this helps someone out there in the ether.  I want to share this now that I've worked out a solution I'm satisfied with.

Here's a solution that's safe and based on [Peter Lamut's write-up](http://www.niteoweb.com/blog/setuptools-run-custom-code-during-install).  Note that this does *not* use shell=True in the subprocess invocation.  You may bypass grunt-task requirements on your python deployment system and also use this for obfuscation and JS packaging all the same.

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install
import subprocess
import os

class CustomInstallCommand(install):
    """Custom install setup to help run shell commands (outside shell) before installation"""
    def run(self):
        dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        template_path = os.path.join(dir_path, 'src/path/to/templates')
        templatejs_path = os.path.join(dir_path, 'src/path/to/templates.js')
        templatejs = subprocess.check_output([
            'nunjucks-precompile',
            '--include',
            '["\\.tmpl$"]',
            template_path
        ])
        f = open(templatejs_path, 'w')
        f.write(templatejs)
        f.close()
        install.run(self)

setup(cmdclass={'install': CustomInstallCommand},
      ...
     )
```

Answer (score -3):

I think that the link [here](https://seasonofcode.com/posts/how-to-add-custom-build-steps-and-commands-to-setuppy.html) encapsulates what you are trying to achieve.