# run system command during pip installation

Tags: python, pip

I have package and installation script `setup.py`.
My package needs to have a additional user in system.
I have to add user manually after installation.

How can pip create user automatically during installation process?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27950551/how-to-execute-a-safe-bash-shell-command-within-setup-py)?

Comment: I guess so, details are here: http://www.niteoweb.com/blog/setuptools-run-custom-code-during-install
Once I find it out, I will publish it here.