# How setup.py install npm module?

Tags: python, npm, setup.py

I implemented a python web client that I would like to test.

The server is hosted in npm registry. The server gets ran locally with node before running my functional tests.

How can I install properly the npm module from my setup.py script?

Here is my current solution inspired from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27950551/how-to-execute-a-safe-bash-shell-command-within-setup-py/27953695#27953695):

```
class CustomInstallCommand(install):
    def run(self):
        arguments = [
            'npm',
            'install',
            '--prefix',
            'test/functional',
            'promisify'
        ]
        subprocess.call(arguments, shell=True)
        install.run(self)

setup(
    cmdclass={'install': CustomInstallCommand},
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
from setuptools.command.build_py import build_py

class NPMInstall(build_py):
    def run(self):
        self.run_command('npm install --prefix test/functional promisify')
        build_py.run(self)
```

OR

```
from distutils.command.build import build

class NPMInstall(build):
    def run(self):
        self.run_command("npm install --prefix test/functional promisify")
        build.run(self)
```

finally:

```
setuptools.setup(
    cmdclass={
        'npm_install': NPMInstall
    },
    # Usual setup() args.
    # ...
)
```

Also look [here](https://dankeder.com/posts/adding-custom-commands-to-setup-py/)

Comment: and if you'd like to do it as part of the build command, here's how: https://jichu4n.com/posts/how-to-add-custom-build-steps-and-commands-to-setuppy/  (same as this answer but use `build_py` as the keyword in `cmdclass`)

Comment: When using the above I get... 

running npm_install
running npm install --prefix app/site/static
error: invalid command 'npm install --prefix app/site/static'

I already have a package.json file in the static directory. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You are very close, Here is a simple function that does just that, you can remove "--global" option is you want to install the package for the current project only, keep in mind the the command shell=True could present security risks

```
import subprocess
def npm_install(args=["npm","--global", "install", "search-index"])
  subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True)
```